# tensorflow network didn't fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp

I have a pandas `dataset` where `col1` -> input text(text tokenize with pre-trained tokenizer),col2 -> binary classification [0,1].
translating it into tensorflow dataset

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: dataset, output_types=(tf.string, tf.int32))
```

create model

```
def build_classifier_model():
   text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='text')
   preprocessing_layer = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_preprocess, name='preprocessing')
   encoder_inputs = preprocessing_layer(text_input)
   encoder = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_encoder, trainable=True, name='BERT_encoder')
   outputs = encoder(encoder_inputs)
   net = outputs['pooled_output']
   net = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(net)
   net = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=None, name='classifier')(net)
   return tf.keras.Model(text_input, net)
classifier_model = build_classifier_model()
```

fine_tune model(bert)

```
epochs = 5
steps_per_epoch = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(dataset).numpy()
num_train_steps = steps_per_epoch * epochs
num_warmup_steps = int(0.1*num_train_steps)

init_lr = 3e-5 
optimizer = optimization.create_optimizer(init_lr=init_lr,
                                      num_train_steps=num_train_steps,
                                      num_warmup_steps=num_warmup_steps,
                                      optimizer_type='adamw')
```

model compile

```
classifier_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                     loss=loss,
                     metrics=metrics)
```

and i begin fit model with loop

```
from tqdm import tqdm
for epoch in range(5):
    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in tqdm(enumerate(dataset)):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        logits = classifier_model(x_batch_train, training=True) 
        loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, logits)
        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, classifier_model.trainable_weights)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, classifier_model.trainable_weights))
        print(step)
        if step % 200 == 0:
            print('loss_value %s: %s' % (step, float(loss_value)))
```

i run this in colab pro with gpu and the cell where this training is performed freezes and does not train the model.
Output:

```
0it [00:00, ?it/s]
```

Help me begin to train my model,please(when i try to fit method `.fit` (`model.fit()`)
the result was the same)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the way you create your Dataset. The `from_generator` function expect a **generator** as first argument and not a function.

Try accessing an element or ispecting it to see if it works. Try for example:

```
next(iter(dataset))
```

and see if it returns the first sample and label.

When you create a tensorflow Dataset from a pandas DataFrame you should use tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(), here an example:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(dataset))
```